# How do I check whether a expression is a function name?

Tags: c++, type-traits

The question is as mentioned in the title, the function may possibly be overloaded or templated and this has to be done at block scope. Here's the best I've got, but it fails on function references

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Fs> struct overload : Fs... {
  using Fs::operator()...;
  std::true_type operator()(...);
};

#define is_funcname(f)                                                         \
  [] {                                                                         \
    auto l = [](auto x) mutable                                                \
        -> std::bool_constant<!std::is_pointer_v<decltype(x, f)>> {            \
      return {};                                                               \
    };                                                                         \
    auto o = overload<decltype(l)>{};                                          \
    return decltype(o(42))::value;                                             \
  }()

void bar() {}
void bar(int) {}

void baz() {}

void foo() {
  static_assert(is_funcname(bar));
  static_assert(!is_funcname((void (*)())bar));
  static_assert(is_funcname(baz));
  static_assert(!is_funcname(+baz));

  auto &r = baz;
  static_assert(!is_funcname(r)); // fails
}
```

The use case is that my library has to decide whether it needs to capture the expression as a type erased context, which might potentially be unsupported on certain platforms and should be avoided.

Comment: Do you consider a class with `operator()` to be a function too?

Comment: What about [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) and [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)?

Comment: @dave They both take types as parameters, which isn't possible with overloaded and templated functions. `std::is_function<decltype(bar)>` in the example won't compile.

Comment: @Petr No, I'm trying to avoid capturing a free function when possible.

Comment: @PasserBy Cannot you just [`remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)?

Comment: @BiagioFesta On what? `decltype(bar)` itself won't compile if that's what you mean.

Comment: Are you compiling C++20? Anyway, g++ head 9.0.1 (wandbox) compile (c++2a) your code (commenting the last `static_assert()`) but clang++ head 9.0.0 gives a compilation error also in first `static_assert()` (cannot resolve `f` in `decltype(x, f)`).

Comment: @max66 C++2a is fine. I didn't check clang, but I'm pretty certain that `x, f` is dependent on `x` and shouldn't be a hard error.